# Instead of vs Instead

Tags: phrases

> 1. When I was a child, I walked to school everyday instead going by cycle.

Is this sentence correct? The following sentence seems better to me:

> 2. When I was a child, I walked to school everyday instead of going by cycle.

Are my intuitions right?

Comment: #1 contradicts itself, saying that you walked but that you cycled.

Answer (score 4):

> **'Instead of'** is a **preposition**. We use it to show one person, thing or action **replaces** another.
>
> E.g: When I was a child, I walked to school every day **instead of**
>   going by a cycle.
>
> She often goes swimming **instead of** going to school.

**Instead** (alone without **of**) is an adverb. It often comes at the beginning or end of a clause.

E.g: When I was a child, I did not use a cycle; **instead** I walked every day.

(*From Michael Swan's PEU*)

Answer (score -2):

"When I was a child, I walked to school everyday instead of going by bicycle."

Comment: Except that the first is oxymoronic.

Comment: The first sentence doesn't make sense, indeed. Something like _When I was a childe, I **never** walked to school, instead going by bicycle_ would make more sense. It would mean the _opposite_ of the second sentence.

Comment: Ha. I just realised I misread it. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: All you have at the moment is simply a restatement of sentence 2. You need to explain why that's correct.